# Foundation 5 - Orbit - HTML5 video does not start

Tags: zurb-foundation

I am trying to add in a short looping video to an Orbit slider, but the video does not actually start. I have found that if I remove "data-orbit" the video will initialize and loop as expected, but I realize that data-orbit is necessary for the slider to initialize. What can I do to have the video actually play?

```
<ul class="example-orbit-content" data-orbit data-options="timer_speed: 5000; pause_on_hover: true; resume_on_mouseout: true; navigation_arrows: true; slide_number: false;  variable_height: false; next_on_click: true; swipe: false;">
                <li>
                    <video autoplay loop poster="resources/cover.jpg" id="bgvid">
                        <source src="resources/corn.webm" type="video/webm">
                        <source src="resources/corn.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    </video>
                </li>

                <li data-orbit-slide="headline-1">
                  <img src="img/dallas.jpg" />
                </li>

                <li data-orbit-slide="headline-2">
                   <img src="img/casey.jpg" />
                </li>

                <li data-orbit-slide="headline-3">
                   <img src="img/jared.jpg" />
                </li>
           </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it has something to do with how the slider processes playing the slider as a whole. I managed to solve the issue by placing

```
<script>$('#bgvid').get(0).play();</script>
```

after

```
<script>$(document).foundation();</script>
```

in the framework.